# Is there a way to shorten this and make it cleaner too read?

Tags: python

```
def toktok(self) -> object:
      tokens = []
      while self.current is not None:
          if self.current == " ":
              self.next()
          elif self.current == '=':
              tokens.append(Token(TT_equal))
              print("C1:", tokens[0], self.current, "C2")
              self.next()
          elif self.current == '+':
              tokens.append(Token(self.current))
              self.Methods()
          elif self.current == '-':
              tokens.append(Token(TT_subtraction))
              self.Methods()
          elif self.current == '*':
              tokens.append(Token(TT_multiplication))
              self.Methods()
          elif self.current == '/':
              tokens.append(Token(TT_division))
              self.Methods()
          elif self.current == '(':
              tokens.append(Token(TT_parenthesis_left))
              self.Methods()
          elif self.current == ')':
              tokens.append(Token(TT_parenthesis_right))
              self.next()
          elif self.current in TT_identifier:
              tokens.append(Token(self.current))
              self.next()
          elif self.current in TT_numbers:
              tokens.append(self.digitm())
          else:
              char = self.current
              self.next()
              print("Not found: ", char)
      return tokens
```

is there any way I can shorten this or make it cleaner looking? I think it looks funky so if there is a way to shorten that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can use a translation dict `symbol1: token1, symbol2: token2` etc

Comment: should `in TT_numbers` have a `self.next()`?

Comment: Very recent versions 3.10, maybe 3.9, can'r remember now, have a very powerful `match` word that is like an old `switch` on steroids.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dictionary` to avoid the chain if-else conditions.

```
def toktok(self) -> object:
    tokens = []
    mapping = {
        '+': Token(TT_addition),
        '-': Token(TT_subtraction),
        '*': Token(TT_multiplication),
        '/': Token(TT_division),
        '(': Token(TT_parenthesis_left),
        }
    mapping_2 = {
        '=': Token(TT_equal),
        ')': Token(TT_parenthesis_right)
    }
    while self.current is not None:
        if self.current == " ":
             self.next()
        elif self.current in mapping:
            tokens.append(mapping.get(self.current))
            self.Methods()
        elif self.current in mapping_2:
            tokens.append(mapping_2.get(self.current))
            self.next()   
        elif self.current in TT_identifier:
              tokens.append(Token(self.current))
              self.next()
        elif self.current in TT_numbers:
            tokens.append(self.digitm())
        else:
            char = self.current
            self.next()
            print("Not found: ", char)
    return tokens
```